# Package problems after upgrade

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I installed a new upgrade on ubuntu which seemed to fail near the end. Now I'm being told that an error has occurred and to please run apt-get to see what's wrong. After some further tries with that I eventually gave up. It seems there's a left over latex package(?) somewhere and I can't seem to get rid of or fix it. Here's an example:

```
    blank@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     tex-common : Breaks: texlive-common (< 2010) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-base : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                    Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-doc-base : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-extra-utils : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
                           Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
     texlive-font-utils : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                          Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-generic-recommended : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-latex-base : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                          Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-latex-base-doc : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-latex-extra : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                           Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-latex-extra-doc : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-latex-recommended : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                                 Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-latex-recommended-doc : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-luatex : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                      Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-pictures : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                        Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-pictures-doc : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-pstricks : Depends: texlive-binaries (>= 2012-0) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
                        Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     texlive-pstricks-doc : Depends: texlive-common (>= 2012.20120516) but 2009-15 is installed
     zlib1g : Breaks: texlive-binaries (< 2009-12) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
     zlib1g:i386 : Breaks: texlive-binaries (< 2009-12) but 2009-11ubuntu2 is installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I've seen similar errors on the site here, but not close enough that i could get it fixed. Any help would be great,
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run `apt-get -f install`?

Comment: Probably this post will help you? `http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96965/problems-with-texlive-2012-on-ubuntu-after-network-installation`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge texlive* tex-common*
```